Warning when using moment-with-locales
../../../../node_modules/moment/min/moment-with-locales.min.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './locale' in 'C:\Users\arnav\node_modules\moment\min'

Import trace for requested module:
../../../../node_modules/moment/min/moment-with-locales.min.js
./node_modules/moment-with-locales-es6/index.js
./src/components/events/EventDetails.jsx
./src/components/events/EventGridLayout.jsx
./src/components/events/SingleEventCard.jsx
./src/components/events/MainPageEeventList.jsx
./src/app/page.js

get this waring when i change moment package to moment-with-locales-es6 package to change the language of months in my website . What does this mean

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].

Corrupted file? Re-install moment? Path incorrect?
